# JavaScript compact if/else into a single line?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I search the DOM with this line: `$(current_form).find('input').data('option')` The result is either: `undefined` or I get back a string of options such as `'x|y|z'` which I then call `split('|')` on to get an array of options as: `['x','y','z']`

Issue is that `split` will throw an error if it is called on `undefined`

**How can I express this in one line?**

*1 of many failed attempts:*

```
var TEXT_EXACT = ( typeof $(current_form).find('input').data('option') === 'undefined' ) ? false : $(this).split('|');
```

Comment: maybe not in one line, but you should look at promises, much clearer!!! Or just code and remove the enters

Comment: How would promises help with a ternary statement ?

Comment: Please don't forget to mark what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: @f1f5 People often look at the wrong problem. Having everything on a single line doesn't make your code more clever or elegant. What about `var options = optionsFrom(current_form);` ? Then it doesn't matter wheter the actual implementation of `optionsFrom` takes 1 or more lines. You should be more concerned about being explicit and having code that reads fluently rather than making it shorter. Remember, functions aren't only useful for code reuse, but also for code organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var TEXT_EXACT = ($(current_form).find('input').data('option') || '').split('|');
```

The usage of `||` as a "default" operator is common, and is described in greater detail here (and other places): http://danielpike.me.uk/guard-and-default-operators-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var value = $(current_form).find('input').data('option') || '';
var TEXT_EXACT =  value.split('|');
```

Comment: That's two lines. The OP is apparently working on an old 24-line terminal, he can't afford that.

Comment: @Barmar, two lines here and two lines there and the next thing you know my code 2x the size. Just trying to keep it tight and succinct. :D

Comment: @f1f5 - In programming, "succinct" can be the mother of "wtf?!?".

Comment: @Jared I try not to cross that line. It's equally arguable that being too explicit may have the same affect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the null coalesce operator - `||` in JS.

```
var TEXT_EXACT = ($(current_form).find('input').data('option') || '' ).split('|');
```

Comment: I think I like this answer better than my own.

Comment: I'm annoyed that it's 1 character too long and it makes the scroll bar appear in SO. :P

Answer (score 1):

If you have to return `false`, and not an empty array like the other answers do, in one line you could do

```
var TEXT_EXACT = (function(v) { return v ? v.split('|') : false; })($(current_form).find('input').data('option'));
```

It should be noted that jQuery will parse arrays in data attributes for you, so if you change from something like this

```
<input data-option="x|y|z" />
```

to an array

```
<input data-option="['x','y','z']" />
```

jQuery's `data()` will parse it for you and you don't need the `split()`, meaning it either returns `undefined`, which is falsy, or an array, so you don't need the if/else at all you can just do

```
var TEXT_EXACT = $(current_form).find('input').data('option');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3rUSL/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var TEXT_EXACT = "".split.call( $(current_form).find('input').data('option') || '', "|" );
```

Comment: This has the advantage of not using closures.